# pictures comes on top of each other

Tags: android, imageview

What should be done until the CSS layout XML code for a solution like this " div " Have such a structure ? . I started writing the new android.
What should be done to prevent the entry of each picture?

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:id="@+id/populist"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/duyuru" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:id="@+id/yokduyuru"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/iibf" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:id="@+id/universiteler"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/kadinakedemisyen" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:id="@+id/kararsız"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_`enter code here`alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/muhendislik" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ViewGroup` such as `LinearLayout` (or `GridLayout` and so on, but other than `FrameLayout`) as the parent `View` of `ImageViews`.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:id="@+id/populist"
        android:src="@drawable/duyuru" />

    (...)

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:id="@+id/kararsız"
        android:src="@drawable/muhendislik" />

</LinearLayout>
```